# In this solution, can someone please explain why we are allowed to substitute b=2f(a)?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation, functional-inequalities

Can someone please explain why we are allowed to substitute $b=2f(a)$? the statement is underlined in red.
What about this situation allows one to make this substitution? Like I cant say, let $af(a)+bf(b)=2f(a)f(b)+1$ because then the inequality obviously wouldn't hold. This substitution doesn't make any sense to me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures of text and equations.  Also, eliminate irrelvant words from your title.  Also:  Show your work.

Comment: I don't know how to make the pictures searchable. What words in my title are irrelevant? I don't have any work to show, I have a question about someone else work. seems like you are being unnecessarily harsh.

Comment: Typeset your text and equations in *MathJax*.  That's how.  Oh.. and "can someone explain to me how..." are clearly irrelevant.  Here's a similar example". "I don't know how to calculate the square root of a negative number so can someone please tell me how to do it?"  Better:  "How to calculate the square root of a negative number."  See the difference?

Comment: You're new here, so I'll be explicit:  "In this solution, can someone please explain why we are allowed to substitute b=2f(a)?"  Do you see why "in this solution" is irrelevant?  Which solution or derivation do you think the problem is relating to... one somewhere *else*?  "can someone please explain" is always irrelevant.  Of *course* your asking for someone to explain or answer something for you.  Of course. "why we are allowed to" is also extraneous, and can easily be written more clearly and succinctly.  OK:  You try!!

Comment: is the goal to help each other get better at math or is the goal to talk about the politics of properly posting?

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with "politics."  And yes of *course* there are whole guidelines on posting that are enforced—some rigidly, others less so.  You choose to ignore the universal rule of typesetting.  Oh well.  Regardless, this is a forum for experts to help novices think more clearly, express their ideas crisply, while avoiding wasting everyone's time.  In doing so they can help some OPs answer questions on their own... here, and elsewhere.  Some OPs get that fact quickly and learn, and become better mathematicians, thinkers, and scholars.  Alas, others do not.

Comment: well, your comments on my post led me to believe that you have an exaggerated sense of self-importance: a quick google search confirmed this belief.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Insinuating that OP (and anyone who does not care to engage with several condescendingly-written paragraphs about how to be more succinct) will not become "better mathematicians, thinkers, and scholars" is really uncalled for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that inequality $2f(a)f(b) \ge af(a) + bf(b)$ holds for any choice of real numbers $a$ and $b$. Since you are free to let $b$ be whatever you like, you can choose $b=f(a)$.

Comment: but I cant say $af(a)+bf(b)=2f(a)f(b)+1$ because I would have no way of knowing whether $2f(a)f(b)+1$ is in the range of $af(a)+bf(b)$? correct?

Comment: @not_tiger You can think of what the author is doing as plugging in a particular value of $a$ and $b$ into the inequality. Like choosing $a=1$, and choosing $b=f(1)$ (since $f(1)$ is just another real number). What you are suggesting ($af(a)+bf(b) = 2f(a) f(b) + 1$) isn't a choice of $a$ and $b$; you can't just assert that the equation holds since you don't know if there exists such a pair $(a,b)$ satisfying the equation.